# Inspecting array after memcpy

Tags: c, memcpy

I'm trying to better understand memcpy. Here's an example I was experimenting with:

```
int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
int dest[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

void *ptr = &dest;

printf("Before copy: %d, %d, %d, %d\n", *(int*)ptr, *(int*)ptr + 1, *(int*)ptr + 2, *(int*)ptr + 3);

memcpy(dest, arr, 3*sizeof(int));

printf("After copy: %d, %d, %d, %d\n", dest[0], dest[1], dest[2], dest[3]);
printf("After copy: %d, %d, %d, %d\n", *(int*)ptr, *(int*)ptr + 1, *(int*)ptr + 2, *(int*)ptr + 3);
```

How am I getting different results from last two print statements? The first one behaves the way I expect, but the second one doesn't.

Comment: You are missing parenthesis around `*(int*)ptr + n`. I suppose you mean `*(int*)(ptr + n)`.

Comment: `3*sizeof(int)` ? 3 times ?

Comment: `void *ptr = &dest` why not `int*` ? Then you can remove all the `(int*)` cast. Like `int* ptr = &dest[0];` or simply `int* ptr = dest;`

Comment: @4386427 I went with void *ptr because I saw that memcpy accepts void* in the parameter: void *memcpy(void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n); However, I see as long as s1 and s2 are the same type, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Maydayfluffy That just means `memcpy` accepts any type of object pointer. They can all be implicitly converted to `void *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting confused by the first `printf` only because `dest` is initialized with consecutive integers. Try

```
int dest[] = { 4, 72, 0, -5 };
```

instead.

Your real problem is operator precedence: `*a + b` parses as `(*a) + b`, not `*(a + b)` (the latter being equivalent to `a[b]`).

---

By the way, I'm not convinced

```
void *ptr = &dest;
*(int *)ptr
```

is legal. The standard says any (object) pointer can be converted to `void *` and back without loss of information, but here you're converting from type A to `void *` to type B (where A != B).

Specifically: `&dest` has type `int (*)[4]` (pointer to array of 4 ints), not `int *`. To fix this, do

```
void *ptr = dest;
```

instead. Or just `int *ptr = dest;`, then you don't even need to cast.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You are probably right about void *ptr = &dest; but changing it to without & made no difference in the output. Not sure what to make of that...

Comment: @Maydayfluffy Yeah, it's very likely to just work on any common platform. I'm just not sure it's *guaranteed* to work everywhere.

Comment: Regarding the conversion through `void*` it appears to be legal ... unless there are alignment issues (see [C99 6.3.2.3p7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.3.2.3p7)).

Comment: @pmg I don't see how that applies here. We never convert our pointer back to `int (*)[4]`.

Comment: "A pointer to an object" [`ptr` pointing to the array] "may be converted to a pointer to a different object" [`(int *)ptr` pointing to an int], but my interpretation is probably wrong.

Comment: @pmg If it's correctly aligned, you don't get undefined behavior, but it doesn't say you can actually do anything with that pointer (except convert it back to its original type).

Comment: The _pointer conversion_ part is legal, as is always the case with `void*`. However, de-referencing it as `int*` is illegal. `&dest` is of type `int(*)[4]`. The effective type of the pointed at object is `int[4]`. `int*` is not a compatible type, so there is a strict aliasing violation. Going the other way around though, from `int*` to `int(*)[]` should be legal, since `int(*)[]` points to an aggregate type containing the effective type `int`.

Comment: Ok, lets agree it's best to avoid these kinds of constructs :)

Answer (score 1):

When you print the values:

```
printf("Before copy: %d, %d, %d, %d\n", *(int*)ptr, *(int*)ptr + 1, *(int*)ptr + 2, *(int*)ptr + 3);
```

You're not printing what you think you are.  The expression `*(int*)ptr + 1` takes `ptr`, converts it to an `int *`, then dereferences that pointer, which gives you the value of the first element, then adds 1 to that element's value.  It does not add to the pointer value because the dereference operator `*` has higher precedence than the addition operator `+`.

You need to add parenthesis to get the behavior you want:

```
printf("Before copy: %d, %d, %d, %d\n", *(int *)ptr, *((int *)ptr + 1), *((int *)ptr + 2), *((int *)ptr + 3));
```